# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64 when decrypting image

Tags: java, android

I am selecting an image using Jsoup parser

```
Elements images = document.select("img");
String src = images.attr("src");
```

then using this code to get rid off `data:image/jpg;base64`

```
pureImageSrc = imageSrc.substring(imageSrc.indexOf(",") + 1);
```

Now I have correct base 64 string (i guess) which starts and ends like

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4Vl6RXhpZgAAT...............lbRIluL+9/56L+VFOoqhH/2Q==
```

finally, I am decoding it and setting inside an image view

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(pureImageSrc, Base64.URL_SAFE);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

But getting this exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64`
What's missing in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are decoding with the flag `Base64.URL_SAFE` which uses `-` and `_` in place of `+` and `/`, your base64 string includes `/`. Try changing the flag to `Base64.DEFAULT`