# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64

Tags: android, base64, android-imageview

I upload encoded String image on image view but I got

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64 error.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
dashboard_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
dashboard_img.invalidate();
```

`Base64.URL_SAFE` also not working for base 64 error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64 when decrypting image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182339/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-base-64-when-decrypting-image)

Comment: Add encoding code .

Answer (score 0):

Check the base64 string you are trying to use. Check if you have something like this "data:image/jpg;base64" preceding then look for a way to remove this first. If you have access to the image string you want to decrypt, I will suggest you don't encode image file with its directory.

Answer (score 0):

val pdfvalue="data:application/pdf;base64,fhkffj"
val base64data= pdfvalue?.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,","")

Remove the base64 annotation from the base64 String data.
it Works fine Me